# Count number of leaf nodes in a generic tree

Tags: java

I am quite sure that my logic is correct but I am getting a wrong answer.
Kindly point out the mistake without changing the logic of my program.

```
public static int countLeaves(TreeNode<Integer> root,int max)
    {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(root==null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if(root.children.size()==0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i < root.children.size(); i++) 
        {
            max = max + countLeaves(root.children.get(i),max);
        }
        
        return max;
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        TreeNode<Integer> root = takeInputLevelWise();
        printTree(root);
        int max = 0;
        
        System.out.println(countLeaves(root, max));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic is not correct so I can't point out your error without changing your logic :-)

The issue is double-counting, here:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < root.children.size(); i++) 
    {
        max = max + countLeaves(root.children.get(i),max);
    }
```

That is, you're passing down `max` (which is the count of leaves so far), *adding* to it, then returning it, and adding *again*.

Think of it from a design perspective. Why should `countLeaves` even need to know your count so far? `countLeaves` should only return the number of leaves under it, right? There's no need for `max` to be passed down.

```
public static int countLeaves(TreeNode<Integer> root)
    {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int leaves = 0;
        if(root==null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if(root.children.size()==0)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < root.children.size(); i++) 
        {
            leaves += countLeaves(root.children.get(i));
        }

        return leaves;
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        TreeNode<Integer> root = takeInputLevelWise();
        printTree(root);

        System.out.println(countLeaves(root));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in Python for count number of leaf node in generic tree is

```
def leafNodeCount(tree):
if len(tree.children) == 0:
    return 1
Num = 0
for child in tree.children:
    Num += leafNodeCount(child)
return Num
```